# Ruby - print first part of string in element of array

Tags: arrays, ruby, printing, split, element

Given an array of strings (full names), I need to print only the first name (hint - I'm required to use an iteration and array method)

Search terms: "ruby print part of element in array", "ruby array split strings", "ruby each array .first", "ruby print element array parameters".

I tested quite a few different possible solutions from stack overflow, I've tried ruby doc and a few other array tutorials and cannot find what I am trying to do. I feel like I am waaaay overthinking this but I cannot get past this one.

**Similar WORKING Code:**

```
full_names = ["Alice Smith", "Bob Evans", "Roy Rogers"]
puts "exercise #4 - print names by line"
full_names.each do |name|
  puts name
end
```

**BROKEN CODE - Last Attempted Code:**

```
puts "exercise #4 - print only first"
full_names = ["Alice Smith", "Bob Evans", "Roy Rogers"]
full_names.each do |name|
  puts name.first
end
```

> Error ex_a.rb:78:in `block in <main>': undefined method`first' for "Alice Smith":String (NoMethodError)
>   (line 78 is 'puts name.first')

Comment: Split the problem into smaller parts. Instead of working with an array of strings, use a single string: `name = "Alice Smith"`. Now try to retrieve that string's first word. Once solved, apply your solution to the loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So close:

```
puts "exercise #4 - print only first"
full_names = ["Alice Smith", "Bob Evans", "Roy Rogers"]
full_names.each do |name|
  puts name.split.first
end
```

Comment: thank you! I found a method that is very similar to yours, but more lengthy. Thank you for posting this, I included your version and mine in my homework so I could reference back later how they both worked!

Answer (score 0):

This is basically the same as steenslag's answer, but you also can do it in one line like so:

```
puts "exercise #4 - print only first"
full_names = ["Alice Smith", "Bob Evans", "Roy Rogers"]
full_names.each { |name| puts name.split.first }
```

or

```
full_names.each { |name| puts name.split[0] }
```

The reason you were getting the error `undefined method: first` is that `first` is a method for the Enumerable and Array class. 
See https://rubyapi.org/2.7/o/array#method-i-first

After you `split` the strings (in this case, names separated by a space), you turn each of them into an array on their own. So `"Alice Smith".split => ["Alice", "Smith"]`. You can then access the first item of this array with `first` or `[0]`, which acesses the first index of any array.

Likewise when you apply [0] to a string, e.g. `"Alice"[0]`, this is the `String#slice` method which accesses the first item of `"Alice"`.

Therefore, `"Alice"[0] => "A"` See: https://rubyapi.org/2.7/o/s?q=slice

Answer (score 0):

While not a big difference, I would avoid `split` and prefer the following approach:

```
puts name[/\S+/] # first word anywhere in the string
```

or

```
puts name[/^\S+/] # word must be at the start of the string
```

The difference could matter if you one day perform the same idea to extract the first word from a long text. With `split`, the whole string will be scanned and a temporary array with all the words will be created, but you need only the first one. With my approach, the string will only be scanned until the first word is identified.

The difference between my two variations is that the second one would extract the first name even if there are leading spaces, such as `"  Alice Smith"`. Plus, this approach can easily extended to include punctuation characters as word separators.